# C# Linq where clause .Contains(string[])

Tags: c#, linq, string, ienumerable

Ive been googling for the last few hours to find a solution to my problem but im stumpped.
I was wondering if someone could help me out with the following.

I have a Linq query that queries against a DataTable. I have a param of string[] BodyTypes that holds strings like "5,7,11" or "6,7,4" or just "5,"

the Linq i have is:

```
 var query2 = (from v in query.AsEnumerable()
                              where  (from yy in BodyTypes       
                                      select yy).Contains(v.Header36.ToString())
                              select new
                              {
                                  PartNumber = v.PartNumber,
                                  Position = v.Position,
                                  ImagePath = v.ImagePath,
                                  Supplier = v.Supplier,
                                  Price = v.Price,
                                  RRP = v.RRP,
                                  Stock = v.Stock,
                                  BaseCat = v.BaseCat,
                                  Description = v.Description,
                                  Header36 = v.Header36,
                                  GT_Id = v.GT_Id
                              });
```

v.Header36 has different values assigned to it per row i.e. "11,7,4,5" or "11,6,7"

My problem is how do i make a match using Linq, i want to match Header36 with anything that is passed in the string[]BodyTypes array like using a wild card or like statement.
My problem is also this DataTable is loaded from a 3rd party's webservice, so no SQL backend can be used here.
Any suggestions would be greatfully appreciated.

Kind Regards
Neil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making it LINQ to Objects actually means it's easier to answer. I think you want something like:

```
from v in query.AsEnumerable()
let headers = v.Header36.Split(',')
where yy.BodyTypes.Intersect(headers).Any()
select new [...]
```

Note that your `(from yy in BodyTypes select yy)` is *mostly* equivalent to just `BodyTypes` (at least it will be given the way you're then using it) - you don't need to use a query expression every time you want to do anything.

Here's a slightly more efficient version:

```
HashSet<String> bodyTypes = new HashSet<String>(yy.BodyTypes);
var query = from v in query.AsEnumerable()
            let headers =  v.Header36.Split(',')
            where bodyTypes.Overlaps(headers)
            select new [...]
```

Comment: Thankyou for your amazingly quick response. I have tried to implement the first code example but i get a syntax error(red undeline) on string.Split(",", v.Header36), i should also add that this is being done inside a Composite Control if that makes any difference.

Comment: dont forget to call .ToString() on Header36

Comment: hmm this line errors -- let headers = string.Split(',', v.Header36.ToString()) with - The best overloaded method match for string.Split(params char[]) has some invalide arguments

Comment: @Neil: Fixed. I always get confused between string.Join being static and string.Split being an instance method. Add in the call to `ToString` if you really need it, but if `Header36` *isn't* already a string, shouldn't it let you get at the component values without having to go via a string representation?

Comment: @GreyCloud: I've deliberately removed the ToString calls for the reason specified in my comment above - either it's *already* a string (in which case ToString is pointless) or it's not, in which case there should be a better way of getting to the values.

Comment: yep v.Header36 is of string type so ive emitted ToString().

Comment: works a treat! :) thank you very much for all you help been stummped for a few hours on this and it works great now.

Answer (score 0):

try using a regex and the .Any method:

```
where  (from yy in BodyTypes  
        select yy).Any( y => (new Regex(v.Header36.ToString())).IsMatch(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood this correct your body time might contain `1,2,3,4` and your Header36 might contain `2,5` and you want to match when an item appears in both delimted strings ?

Change your where clause

```
where  (from yy in BodyTypes select yy)
    .Any(bts=> bts.Split(',').Any(bt=> v.Header36.Split(',').Contains(bt)) )
```

Comment: That's going to be calling `Split` an awful lot... it's not too hard to make it rather simpler.