# Find Partial String Matches Using LINQ Without Loops

Tags: c#, string, linq

**The problem:** I am searching through a collection of user roles within a custom Identity object.  The roles have a department concatenated to them so the role is not just "Role" but has a pattern of "Department:Role".

Since the roles are defined within an object that does not know about the "Department" portion, this part needs to be ignored when building the authorization list.  **Effectively, I am looking for ":Role" within each "Department:Role" item.**

I am using LINQ to do this and have it working (posted below) but I would like to simplify it by removing the `foreach` loops, if possible.  I have been looking online for a few hours now and tried many different solutions.  The two closest to what I am trying to accomplish seem to be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433853/c-sharp-linq-where-clause-containsstring) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194930/how-do-i-use-linq-containsstring-instead-of-containsstring).  Maybe the answer is within those and I am just not grokking it.

Thanks in advance for help/suggestions.

**My code:**

```
protected static void AddObjectAuthorizationRules() {

    //Code that gets current user context...

    string[] pDefinedRoles = new string[] { "Developer", "Admin", "User" };
    List<string> _createRoles = ProcessAuthorizationRoles(pDefinedRoles, pIdentity);

    //Object authorization code that uses _createRoles...
}

private List<string> ProcessAuthorizationRoles(string[] pDefinedRoles, CustomIdentityClass pIdentity) {
    List<string> _allowRoles = new List<string>();
    foreach (var _role in pDefinedRoles) {
        var partial = string.Format(":{0}", _role);
        string[] tmp = (from r in pIdentity.Roles 
                        where r.Contains(partial) 
                        select r).ToArray();
        foreach (string found in tmp) {
            _allowRoles.Add(found);
        }
    }
    return _allowRoles;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use lists rather than arrays, you can try something like this.

```
private List<string> ProcessAuthorizationRoles(List<string> pDefinedRoles, CustomIdentityClass pIdentity)
{
    return pIdentity.Roles.FindAll(x => pDefinedRoles.Exists(y => x.Contains(string.format(":{0}", y))));
}
```

Comment: Marking as answered because it solves my problem and is simple.  At first I was hesitant about changing the string array to a list but the team will be touching that part of the code anyway and there is nothing stopping us from using lists.  Thanks @derbal213!

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have it down to a single return statement for you, but I don't have the reference to "CustomIdentityClass" so I can't test this for you.

```
private List<string> ProcessAuthorizationRoles(string[] pDefinedRoles, CustomIdentityClass pIdentity)
{
    return (from role in (from r in pDefinedRoles
                          select new
                          {
                              Partial = string.Format(":{0}", r)
                          })
            from r in pIdentity.Roles
            where r.Contains(role.Partial)
            select r).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @SpikeX.; The main thing within CustomIdentityClass I am looking at is the .Roles property which is just a List<string>.  Your answer works but performance-wise, how does this compare to @derbal213's suggestion?  I am not familiar enough with LINQ's inner workings to know whether one will be better than the other.  It is possible to use lists instead of arrays for the pDefinedRoles parameter, if that helps.

Comment: Lists and arrays are about the same, performance-wise (there are some differences but unless you're dealing with large data, it generally doesn't matter). Typically speaking, LINQ is more "pretty" but not quite as performant as other, bulkier code. Of course each situation is different, and LINQ certainly has its place, too. If you don't have thousands of items you're querying in your array/list/collection, you can usually use LINQ without a noticeable overhead.